# PyMongo Pass "find" function to a MongoDB request

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

My task: copy the information from the field **'ACCOUNT'** from one document (*123*) and paste it into another document (*456*). Both documents are in the same database and the same collection. This is triggered by a client (Windows) using pymongo:

```
# ... creating the target_collection object ...    

info_id = 123  # the document with this id contains the info which shall be written into the new entry
write_data = target_collection.find_one({'_id': info_id})['ACCOUNT'] # extract the info
update_query = {'$addToSet': {'ACCOUNT': {'$each': [write_data]}}}  
target_doc = {'_id': 456}

target_collection.update_one(target_doc, update_query, upsert=True)
```

This code snippet works totally fine, but it is doing two round trips (fetch the info from 123, write it to 456), which makes the transaction not atomic and slows it down significantly. With the Mongo Shell I am able to do this:

```
db.audit.update(
{_id: 456},
{$addToSet: {'ACCOUNT': {$each: db.getCollection('audit').findOne({_id: 123})["ACCOUNT"] } } }
);
```

How can I achieve the same in pymongo? Is it possible to send a query string to the server?

Versions I use:

- MongoDB 4.4 (on RHEL 7)
- pymongo 3.11.4 (on Windows 10)

Comment: I feel, it is still two round trips. You need to do a **Updates With Aggregation Pipeline** to do a single round trip - this is used to update a document using another field's value within the same document.

Comment: I looked into Aggregation Pipelines, but I don't really understand how this can be applied to the problem above. Do you have an example?

Comment: [Updates With Aggregation Pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/) is introduced with MongoDB v4.2.